# Selected(Checked) data to be showed as a JSON structure using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Have table and checkboxes, if checkboxes are checked and click on button, need to display checked rows data as a JSON structure. I tried the below code, data is getting null.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxhntbgq/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnGet").click(function() {
    var data = [];
    var $headers = $("#Table1").find("th");
    var $rows = $("#Table1").find("tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index) {
      $cells = $(this).find("td");
      data[index] = {};
      $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
        data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
      });
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>


<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Table1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Customer Id</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Name</th>
    <th style="width:120px">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John Hammond</td>
    <td>United States</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Mudassar Khan</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Suzanne Mathews</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Robert Schidner</td>
    <td>Russia</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Get Selected" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line `$(this).find("td:not(:first)")` Since this refers to your checkbox and that does not have any `td`. So you need to use:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:first)")
```

I've added `:not(:first)` to simple remove the `checkbox` when we create the object. You can remove it if you wish.

**Demo**

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btnGet").click(function() {
        var data = [];
        var $headers = $("#Table1").find("th:not(:first)");
        var $rows = $("#Table1").find("tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index) {
          $cells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:not(:first)");
          data[index] = {};
          $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
            data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
          });
        });

        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      });

    });
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Table1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th style="width:80px">Customer Id</th>
        <th style="width:120px">Name</th>
        <th style="width:120px">Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John Hammond</td>
        <td>United States</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Mudassar Khan</td>
        <td>India</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Suzanne Mathews</td>
        <td>France</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Robert Schidner</td>
        <td>Russia</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Get Selected" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Many isssues. Most important was using .eq(cellIndex) instead of [cellIndex]

I ignore the cell with the checkbox using `if (cellIndex>0)` but you can use the selector from the other answer too

```js
$(function() {
  const $headers = $("#Table1 thead tr th"); 
  $("#btnGet").on("click", function() {
    const data = [];
    $("#Table1 tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index) {
      $row = $(this).closest("tr");
      $cells = $row.find("td"); // or use some selector to ignore the first cell
      data[index] = {};
      $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
        if (cellIndex>0) data[index][$headers.eq(cellIndex).html()] = $(this).html();
      });
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>


<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Table1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th style="width:80px">Customer Id</th>
      <th style="width:120px">Name</th>
      <th style="width:120px">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John Hammond</td>
      <td>United States</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mudassar Khan</td>
      <td>India</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Suzanne Mathews</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Robert Schidner</td>
      <td>Russia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Get Selected" />
```